# Fetch SQL Server data into S3 using AWS Glue

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, aws-glue, pyodbc

I'm fetching a list of tables from SQL Server into S3 using AWS Glue. I created a Spark job and passed the table list through the Glue job's parameter as a comma separated string and below is my code to process it:

```
tables = args["table_to_process"]

for tbl in tables: 
   sync_data(tbl, glue_context...)
```

The function `sync_data`:

```
def sync_data(tbl, glue_context...): 
    df = get_glue_df_from_mssql(glue_context, sql) 
    write_glue_df_to_s3(df, s3_path)
```

and the function `get_glue_df_from_mssql`:

```
def get_glue_df(
    glue_context: GlueContext,
    sql: str,
    secret: str,
    logger: logging.Logger
) -> DynamicFrame:
    secret_map = get_secret_map(secret_id=secret)
    jdbc_url = get_sqlserver_conn_str(secret_map=secret_map)
    spark = glue_context.spark_session
    logger.info(f"select statement to execute: {sql}")
    jdbcdf = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
        .option("url", jdbc_url) \
        .option("query", sql) \
        .option("user", secret_map.get('username')) \
        .option("password", secret_map.get('password')) \
        .option("driver", 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver') \
        .load()
    gluedf = DynamicFrame.fromDF(jdbcdf, glue_context, "glue_df")

    return gluedf
```

The code works fine except it's processing the table one by one, no parallelisation hence taking quite long time to complete.

I googled and modified the for loop to below:

```
    # Load the table list into a spark data frame 
    df = spark.createDataFrame(tables, StringType())
    df.rdd.map(process_table).collect()
    # df.foreach(process_table) --An alternative approach
```

Now here the problem(s) come:

- My current code of getting data from mssql require `glue_context`. If I pass `glue_context` to `process_table` function, the job will fail because of serialisation error.
- If I instantiate the `glue_context` within the `process_table` function, it fails with error: `RuntimeError: SparkContext should only be created and accessed on the driver.`
- I have also attempted to remove spark dependency within the worker node by using pyodbc / sqlalchemy but a whole other set of problems of lib dependencies rises. I have seen articles advising how to fix the dependencies in lambda but not much discussed in glue.

Any advice would be appreciated.